# Bootstrap3 datetimepicker DATE format rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I'm using Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker in rails app. Here is my js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

And I need to reformat date type into `Year-Month-Day Time`

I've tried

```
$(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd H:i'    
    });
});
```

But after adding format line script doesn't work. Any ideas?

UPD

```
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :start_time, 'StartTime' %>
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
        <%= text_field :start_time, nil, class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is using

Comment: try it as follows: $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
     format:'d.m.Y H:i'
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me as follows:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the dateFormat and timeFormat differently. Below is the code for reference:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat:  "HH:mm"
});
```

Comment: same error, datetimepicker stop working after adding this. Without working good

Comment: If there are any javascript errors you can check those using browser's inspect element. Rightclick >> Inspect element >> console tab ( If you are using google chrome browser)

Comment: Ok, moreover are you sure that the element that you are applying datetimepicker to has the class of "datetimepicker" and not ID of "datetimepicker"

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers for this question didn't work for me. But this worked:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
})
```